# Hadoop 3.2.1 and HBase 2.2.3 incompatability: ERROR in hadoop-functions.sh

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hadoop3

I am running Hadoop 3.2.1 and Hbase 2.2.3 on Centos8. I downloaded Hadoop from an Apache mirror following the Apache documentation precisely. Hadoop works just fine. I then downloaded HBase from an Apache mirror and followed the Apache documentation precisely.

When i try to run `hbase version` i receive this error:

```
/usr/hdeco/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2366: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_USER: bad substitution
/usr/hdeco/hadoop/bin/../libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2461: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.HADOOP.HBASE.UTIL.GETJAVAPROPERTY_OPTS: bad substitution
```

HBase then goes on to print out the version information. if I run `hbase-daemon.sh start master`, i receive the same error, but `HMaster` does not show up in `jps`.

As per the Apache HBase documentation, because I am running a Hadoop version greater than 3.0.0, i have deleted all the jar files in the `hbase/lib` directory that contained the word hadoop. I received the same error both before and after deleting these jar files.

This is my first time posting anywhere. If I have not included enough, or the right, information, please let me know what you would like me to provide.

Comment: Any update on above post? Facing similar issues with hadoop 3.2.1 and Hbase 2.3.4